# ¿Cuanto esfuerzo se espera de los usuarios de Stack Overflow?

Tags: discusión, propuesta-de-faq, calidad-de-publicaciones

<sub>Basado en la pregunta de Meta.SO [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)</sub>

Sé que algo de esfuerzo de investigación es esperado de parte de los usuarios de Stack Overflow antes de que publiquen una pregunta, pero no estoy seguro de cuánto esfuerzo es considerado adecuado.

He publicado preguntas porque no he encontrado resultados claros en los motores de búsqueda, incluso luego de estar buscando durante casi una hora. Aun así, parece que uno de los usuarios de Stack Overflow no ha estado satisfecho con la cantidad de esfuerzo que le he puesto a mi pregunta y me ha respondido con un comentario crítico (y rudo). ¿Debería tomar su consejo y abstenerme de pedir ayuda incluso si no soy capaz de responder mi propia pregunta con una cantidad de esfuerzo razonable?

Comment: Ya habiendo terminado, siento un poco ironico que la unica pregunta que hice en el sitio en español se pudiera arreglar tambien con una busqueda de google. Todos hacemos malas preguntas

Comment: Respondiendo a tu duda, es totalmente aceptable traducir preguntas del sitio en inglés (siempre enlazando a la publicación original como bien has hecho), siempre que sean útiles a la hora de aclarar dudas a los usuarios de aqui. Gracias por tomarte el tiempo de hacerlo :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<sub>Respuesta basada en la respuesta aceptada de [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/1983854)</sub>

Un montón. Hacer una pregunta en Stack Overflow tiene que ser el ultimo paso en tu proceso de buscar una respuesta - si la información que necesitas ya existe,
entonces quieres encontrarla.

Tú quieres:

- Buscar. Como loco.
- Probar tu código.
- Diagnosticar errores.
- Buscar libros.
- Seguir tutoriales.

Después de haber alcanzado el final de la cuerda con el dolor de no tener una respuesta, entonces puedes ir adelante a hacer una pregunta. Porque en ese momento, tu ya vas a haber hecho suficiente investigación para hacerla una buena pregunta, una  que vale la pena hacer. Vas a tener notas que podrás compartir para ayudar a los que te respondan a saber que es lo que necesitas.
Vas a tener el conocimiento necesario para entender esas repuestas cuando lleguen. No vas a tener que batallar con una versión duplicada y mal escrita de una respuesta mejor que se puede encontrar en algún lugar del sitio. Tampoco vas a sufrir la frustración de tener tu pregunta cerrada, y los que la lean no van a tener la frustración de tener que cerrarla.

El punto importante sigue siendo que nosotros deseamos por encima de todo que seas tu quien hace su propia tarea. Entiende que nuestro tiempo no es gratis, aunque nosotros no estemos cobrando por el. Responder preguntas de baja calidad, con poca investigación, o duplicadas se vuelve cansado.

Y, si el comentario que te colocaron es en realidad rudo - deberías reportarlo. Pero también tienes que asumir buena fe y tratar de entender la frustración que lo motivó, aspirando a hacer un mejor trabajo en el futuro. Buscar e investigar es una habilidad, y la maestría se adquiere con la práctica - las habilidades que ganes en el camino te van a servir durante mucho tiempo.

Answer (score 3):

El mismo esfuerzo que esperan de quienes respondemos. No esperan respuestas escuetas, sin probar, que no funcionen o similares. Con una diferencia fundamental: el más interesado en hacer que se entienda la pregunta debe ser quien pregunta. Pero es un gran *meeting halfway* entre quien pregunta y los que intentamos responder o al menos guiar la pregunta para que tenga todos los detalles necesarios; estarle sacando información al OP cual interrogatorio y que simplemente elijan no dar información como si fuésemos gurús de la informática (qué más quisiera yo)... eso no está bien.

Answer (score -1):

En ese orden de ideas, ¿es deber del que responde preguntarse por la calidad de la consulta antes de responderla? ¿se ignoraría la pregunta?,¿O simplemente se abogaría al altruismo respondiendo de inmediato aún sabiendo que la respuesta podría facilmente encontrarse con una búsqueda más rigurosa?